# Click on Highcharts pie rendering border although legend item click is disabled

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

I am showing a donut chart and although I have disabled the default on legend item click, it is still showing border around the chart. Behavior that happens on legend item click:

[image]

```js
 plotOptions: {
            pie: {
              borderColor: null,
              point: {
                events: {
                  // prevent click events on the legend
                  legendItemClick: function (e) {
                    return e.preventDefault();
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          },
```

Can you please help on how to disable this?
Thanks.
Update: [Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/cmqbfk3y/1/#&togetherjs=TdT1bFrAUc)

Update: the behavior doesn't happen only on legend item click but also on hover.

Comment: Could you reproduce your case on some online editor to see the whole of your chart config?

Comment: yes, updated the question with fiddle link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the series `states` options is a solution to your issue.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w7jyr2zh/

```
states: {
    hover: {
        enabled: false
    },
    inactive: {
        enabled: false
    }
}
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.states.inactive